# Visual Studio not publishing database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, publishing

I am programming in VB.net using visual studio 2012.

My problem is that the database is not included in the published package.

Also, the connection string I'm using specifies a full directory and file path to the database file I'm using. If I give my program to someone else he surely would not have the same directory and will receive an error.

How do I include the database file in my publish, and what should my connection string look like?Kindly guide me.

---

### Connection String

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=**C:\Users\Muhammad Arsalan KB\Documents\Management Database.mdf**;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

Comment: hmm.. have you tried going to property window and make the dbfile (if that's what you're talk about) build as 'content'. that will tell the compiler to include the file in the building of the project..

Comment: whether or not this build action reflects in the publishing process or not, remains to be seen.. I suspect it will

Comment: excuse me.. there is a `Copy to Output` setting in the property window, and it should be Build Action `Content`..

Comment: Even if it's included in the package, what about the problem of connection string I mean how the other users would be able to use it because they may not have the same directory specified in connection string

Comment: please update your question: include your connection string (replacing sensitive info with XXXX). You're tagging this question as sql-server, but making reference to directories.. that's a conflict..

Comment: if you are using a connection string to read from a dbfile.. then that file should be part of your project solution (added as an existing file).. if you 'copy to output', the directory (folders) relative to your project should be created.. your connection string should be composed of relative paths

Comment: is this an ASP.NET or Win project solution? (it can be both of course)

Comment: I updated your question, but can you include whether you are specifying this connection string in the web.config or app.config file?.. or whether you are assigning it to a ADO.NET object, like System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.. I suspect it was the latter, but not certain..

Comment: I actually am using connection string before opening the connection.